# parsing csv with two values in 1 column

Tags: c#, .net

I am parsing this csv file below

```
filename(hhmmss),set,code,timeofday
130052,NULL,ES,"day,dawn"
130053,"1,2",ES,"day,dawn"
130062,NULL,ES,"day,dawn"
130063,"1,2",ES,"day,dawn"
130067,"1,2",ES,"day,dawn"
```

I am parsing the rows like that

```
DataRow oDataRow = dTable.NewRow();
for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
{
    oDataRow[columnNames[i]] = oStreamDataValues[i] == null ? string.Empty : oStreamDataValues[i];
}
dTable.Rows.Add(oDataRow);
```

Q1 : I do notice that at those type of columns there is oStreamDataValues[3] "\"day" and "" at the end of oStreamDataValues[4] value. However, am unable to find a good way to do it ?

Q2 : Also, I am interested in producing statistics from this, how can I create rows with unique values grouped by filename hhmm ie. 13005 ?

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel? Use an available CSV parser like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). They support also quoting characters(for instance). The linked can also load a `DataTable` directly.

Comment: am going to right away :P

Comment: Where is the parsing code??

Comment: @TimSchmelter am not sure I can understand the code, would you be able to give me a snippet ? or where exactly ? am a novice :)

Comment: @user2708115: As you've already noticed i have added an answer, note that i've edited it to answer your second question.

Comment: yeah I was just saying YES ! when I tried it and its working perfectly ! many thanks ! I appreciate when veterans like you actually spend time with such rookie questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you reinvent the wheel? Use an available CSV parser like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

They support also quoting characters(among other things). The above can  also load a `DataTable` directly. Here is a working sample:

```
DataTable tblCSV = new DataTable("CSV");
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullPath);
var encoding = Encoding.Default;
int headerIndex = 0;
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileInfo.FullName, encoding))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < headerIndex; i++)
        reader.ReadLine(); // skip all lines but header+data
    Char quotingCharacter = '"';
    Char escapeCharacter = quotingCharacter;
    Char commentCharacter = '\0'; // none
    Char delimiter = ',';
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, true, delimiter, quotingCharacter, escapeCharacter, commentCharacter, ValueTrimmingOptions.All))
    {
        csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ParseError;
        csv.DefaultParseErrorAction = ParseErrorAction.RaiseEvent;
        csv.ParseError += csv_ParseError;  // the method that handles this error
        csv.SkipEmptyLines = true;
        try
        {
            // load into DataTable
            tblCSV.Load(csv, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, csvTable_FillError); // csvTable_FillError-> the method that handles this error
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // logging 
            throw;
        }
    }
}

void csv_ParseError(object sender, ParseErrorEventArgs e)
{
    // if the error is that a field is missing, then skip to next line
    if (e.Error is MissingFieldCsvException)
    {
        //Log.Write(e.Error, "--MISSING FIELD ERROR OCCURRED!" + Environment.NewLine);
        e.Action = ParseErrorAction.AdvanceToNextLine;
    }
    else if (e.Error is MalformedCsvException)
    {
        //Log.Write(e.Error, "--MALFORMED CSV ERROR OCCURRED!" + Environment.NewLine);
        e.Action = ParseErrorAction.AdvanceToNextLine;
    }
    else
    {
        //Log.Write(e.Error, "--UNKNOWN PARSE ERROR OCCURRED!" + Environment.NewLine);
        e.Action = ParseErrorAction.AdvanceToNextLine;
    }
    // log
}

void csvTable_FillError(object sender, FillErrorEventArgs e)
{
    // You can use the e.Errors value to determine exactly what went wrong.
    if (e.Errors.GetType() == typeof(System.FormatException))
    {
        // log
    }

    // Setting e.Continue to True tells the Load
    // method to continue trying. Setting it to False
    // indicates that an error has occurred, and the 
    // Load method raises the exception that got you here.
    e.Continue = true;

    string errors = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.Errors);
    // log
}
```

**Edit**: According to your second question:

> Q2 : Also, I am interested in producing statistics from this, how can
>   I create rows with unique values grouped by filename hhmm ie. 13005 ?

You can use `LINQ-To-DataSet` to query your `DataTable`, for example:

```
var fileNameGroups = tblCSV.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("filename(hhmmss)"));
```

Now you have one group per unique file-name and each contains all rows:

```
foreach(var fnGroup in fileNameGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Next File-name: {0}", fnGroup.Key);
    foreach(DataRow row in fnGroup)
        Console.WriteLine("Fields: {0}", string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Q1: A good and reliable way to solve this are regular expressions. If you haven't used them before, it might require some reading, but you can use them at various occasions. From my experience this is well worth the effort. For .NET, you can start at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx

An alternative, quick and dirty approach that has its weaknesses is to split by commas (","), iterate over the items and check whether an item starts with a quotation mark:

- If it doesn't start with a quotation mark, it is a single field.
- If it starts with a quotation mark, add this and all subsequent items to the field until one ends with a quotation mark. Strip the quotation marks from the field.

@Q2: I'd suggest to create a data structure that contains the fields of a data row as properties of a matching type (e.g. for field 1 TimeSpan or DateTime if you can come up with an appropriate value for the date part). After that you can read the file content to a list and query or aggregate it with Linq.

Comment: I do know about regular expressions, but the loop gives one at a time, so am thinking of just simply putting an if for containing a / and combine the two, but then it will fail when two consecutive columns have multiple values :( can you help :) ?

Comment: If updated my answer with a quick-and-dirty approach for Q1. Hope this helps.